# HTTP Response data being Truncated

Tags: apex, json, string, httprequest, http

I am making a http request and getting response in JSON . When I am converting it to String using `request.toString()` but getting the truncated response
response sample(This is the part of response which is causing issue) : `params={account_code=il-496-8886, contact[id]=0, form_id=53774,  page_id=68351, survey_field[10]=abc, survey_field[11]=abc, survey_field[12]=abc, survey_field[13]=abc, survey_field[14]=abc, ...}`

But when i loop through this object before converting it to string it is giving all fields like below :

```
for(String str : request.params.keySet()){
            System.debug('====Key===='+str);
            System.debug('====Value===='+request.params.get(str));
        }
```

I am not sure how to convert it to string with out truncating it.Please help me if I am missing anything.

Comment: It might be only truncated in debug logs that are being shown. Are you sure that those are being truncated when sent to 3-rd party?

Comment: Actually I am putting this in a field record value and its showing truncated in that field also.

Comment: for better debugging and full view of object use `System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(request.params));`

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrBerehovskyi , it worked for me , I am able to get all the fields without any truncation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(request)); method as suggested by @OleksandrBerehovskyi and it worked for me . I was able to get all the fields in the system field.